# Android O(reo) Broadcast Receiver not firing.

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I once had a broadcast receiver defined in my manifest to receive the Phone State, like this...

```
<receiver
            android:name=".TelephonyManagerReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

I know in Android O I need to remove this and register the receiver in code, so I've done this...

```
 private BroadcastReceiver callReceiver;

 @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

         callReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
             @Override
             public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

                 Log.i("Phone","received");
             }
         };

         this.registerReceiver(
                 callReceiver,
                 new IntentFilter(TelephonyManager.ACTION_PHONE_STATE_CHANGED)
         ); }
```

I'd expect to see some logging when I receive/make a call, but I do not. Any ideas?

Comment: This has already been asked today. And answered.

Comment: ..and no, it still doesn't fire when set up in a foreground service.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I added two dynamic permissions: CALL_PHONE, READ_PHONE_STATE and receiver is working well even if it's declared only in Manifest file. 
I tested solution on emulator and also on phone - Nexus 5.

(This way it's working when app is open or in background, if you close app it won't work. For this I think you have to use foreground service)

I hope it's not too late.

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the permission in the manifest and also request the permission at runtime?

Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
```

Runtime:

```
private static final int REQUEST_PHONE_STATE = 1;
private static String[] PERMISSIONS_PHONE_STATE = {
            Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE
};

public static void verifyPhonePermissions(Activity activity) {
    // Check if we have this permission
    int permission = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE);

    if (permission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // We don't have permission so prompt the user
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                activity,
                PERMISSIONS_PHONE_STATE,
                REQUEST_PHONE_STATE
        );
    }
}
```